# Program that prints one letter at a time

Tags: python

So, I basically need help on how to make words into a "rainbow", for example:

H

He

Hel

Hell

Hello

Hell

Hel

He

H

He

Hel

And so on.

The only thing I kinda managed to do is this in Python is the first letter to the last, H to Hello, but then I have no idea how to reverse it. Please show me how you would do this.

Comment: if it is homework please show what you have done so far. Thanks and welcome.

Comment: It's not really homework, it just randomly stumbled upon my mind, so kind if my own little project. 
I don't know how to copy and paste on Ipad because it doesn't work but basically, I start with a list = [], then I ask the user for a phrase, calling it the variable "phrase". Then I do for n in range(0, len(phrase)). I later add it into the list, list.append(phrase[n]), like so, and lastly I print the list. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: use itertools permutations on your list

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer in C#:

```
using System;

public class Simple {
  public static void Main() {  
    string Text = "Hello";
    for (int i=0;i < Text.Length;i++)
        Console.WriteLine(Text.Substring(0,i+1));
    for (int i=Text.Length;i > 1;i--)
        Console.WriteLine(Text.Substring(0,i-1));
  }
}
```

In Python:

```
text = "Hello"
for x in range(1, len(text)+1):
  print(text[0:x])
for x in range (1, len(text)):
  print(text[0:len(text)-x])
```

You can also wrap the code above in a function and call it as many times as you need, in order to repeat your rainbow word as many times as you want.

For example, if you want to run it 10 times, you can do something like this:

```
def my_function(text):        
    for x in range(1, len(text)+1):
      print(text[0:x])
    for x in range (1, len(text)):
      print(text[0:len(text)-x])


for x in range(1,10): #It will run it 10 times
    my_function("Hello")
```

Comment: sorry, I should have been more specific, I know only a bit Python and no C# at all.

Comment: I just edited my answer and added the equivalent code in Python. I hope it helps @lezeux

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: I just changed it a little bit, asking the user for a phrase instead of it saying "Hello" all the time. Thank you for the help, I appriciate it!